# Import xls, xlsx files with UTL_FILE ORACLE PACKAGE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

good evening,

I am going to use UTL_FILE to upload files to the oracle database, but the format that they send me exported from the system is in XLSX, is there any way to read the excel files. (I know there is no problem for csv and txt files)

but I can't change the structure or data of the files. is there any way to load the files with UTL_FILE,

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for that, an xslx parser in apex.[Easy XLSX Parser: Just with SQL and PL/SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/easy-xlsx-parser:-just-with-sql-and-plsql) An other option could be to use a python script to do the conversion and upload the data. The advantage of this is that it can be done from a client instead of the database server, making it a bit more acceptable.